# /oauth/token from Controller

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I want to implement oauth2 in my website.
I have the server configured.
In current scenario there is a login page, where user puts her credentials which in turn is submitted to my login controller. Now I want to authenticate user using oauth2. Since the server and client are part of same application I am wondering how to go ahead.
I want to authenticate the user via oauth and return the dashboard along with the bearer token so that next call can me made from here.

Please suggest how to go ahead. If there is a better way to do i am more than happy to adapt it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure authorization server with spring-security-oauth. All the necessary endpoints will be mapped automatically (including /oauth/token)
2. Make a simple webpage with login form
3. Make POST request to /oauth/token with the username and password. In addition you have to send field called grant_type which will be filled with 'password' value.

   4. As a response you will receive the access token. This means that you are authenticated.

P.S. Please pay attention that Oauth is the authorization standard, not the authentication one!

Comment: Thanks @nKognito. I have done the config and the resource are protected but since the client are jsp pages, the user would only give the username password. Now does the controller internally makes a call to the authorization server and extracts token and provide it to client for further communication. The idea of making rest call internally does not looks right to me.. Also if I implement it I am not sure how to hande expired tokens.